# Creating a bookmarklet using js

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

In need of some help! 
I got somehow lost, playing around with window.location.assign or window.location.pathname.. 
I'm trying to change the part of the url and load it in the same window
For example, I have www.example.com/en/index.html (real link is more complicated), I want to change it to www.example.com/es/index.html and load the new page.
Really appreciate any suggestions
Thank you,
Yan

Comment: did you try using `window.location.assign("www.example.com/es/index.html")`

Comment: The key idea here is to make a universal bookmarklet, link could be longer, than the example, but in any case with only one difference (/es/ and /en/). I suppose regex shall ve used to  indicate what Part of the URL is to be replaced, but I do not get how to join regex and window.location.assign... 

Comment: Looks like this code works `code` javascript:(function(){location.replace(window.location.href.replace("http://example.com/en/","http://example.com/es/"))})();  So the only question is if I have more that two languages, how can I add for example /fr/ here, so the bookmarklet will switch from both to /es/

Answer (score 0):

Solved! ))
Here is the code do switch between two languages back and forth

```
javascript:(function chooseLang(e){var pathName=window.location.pathname;var pathArray=(pathName.substring(0,1)=='/')?pathName.substring(1).split('/'):pathName.split('/');if(pathArray[0]=='es')pathArray[0]='en';else if(pathArray[0]=='en')pathArray[0]='es';;window.location.href=window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host+'/'+pathArray.join('/');})();
```

also, here is one to switch to a specific one (in case you are having many on the page)

```
javascript:(function chooseLang(e){var pathName=window.location.pathname;var pathArray=(pathName.substring(0,1)=='/')?pathName.substring(1).split('/'):pathName.split('/');pathArray[0]='es';window.location.href=window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host+'/'+pathArray.join('/');})();
```

Hope it might be usefull to someone :)